# IDE for JavaScript development

Tags: javascript, ide

What do you suggest for JS development IDE. Is there something similar to VisualStudio IDE, so I can run/debug my application in it?

Comment: WebStorm from www.jetbrains.com is excellent for JavaScript, because it supports ECMAScript 5, understands JsDoc perfectly (inheritance and all). It's the only IDE that actually does that.

Comment: @Tower I agree, I used PHPStorm for a while for PHP and js development, and its js support is great. Now I think I ended my PHP carrier, I never liked that language. Javascript is my never ending love. I just bought WebStorm. :-)

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/3 is my favorite

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few options:

- Visual Studio 2008 (including VWD Express, http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/)
- Adobe Dreamweaver CS4
- Notepad++ (or any other text editor), Firefox and Firebug

Comment: Notepad++ sucks at autocomplete.

Comment: Visual Studio is just perfect... it has full code completion. Once you learn the secret put these comments at the top of any jscript file /// <reference path="lib/jquery-1.7.1.js" /> to import any external js for code completion (intellij)

Comment: Visual Studio does not offer refactoring.

Comment: Is Firefox and Firebug an IDE for JS?

Comment: For anyone interested here is a fixed link for the outdated link in this post: http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Visual studio code is also a user-friendly IDE for beginners.

Answer (score 45):

At JetBrains we've just developed lightweight [HTML/Javascript/CSS IDE WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) that includes very smart JavaScript Editor with DOM-based autocompletion and HTML5 API support.
It allows you to debug(breakpoints supported) and run your scripts directly from IDE.

Comment: There are many other ways to share your expertise on Stack Overflow that dont involve promoting your company. While you have made the proper disclosure, please try answers that don't link to your company, too.

Comment: He's not promoting anything.  This answers the question perfectly and doesn't make any claims as to being superior to other solution.  It's pertinent information and nothing more.

Comment: @Mr Grieves - take a look at 100% of his answers to questions.   While reading his answers, compare the first sentences to all his answers.

Comment: JetBrains does make a mean IDE.

Answer (score 16):

I think IntellJ's JavaScript support is excellent, just like everything else that they do.

Comment: link http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 13):

**Netbeans 6.x and Firefox+Firebug**

In the past I used **Aptana** Standalone or as a Eclipse plugin. The Pro version has some nice addons like the embedded IE (to the always embedded Firefox) and debugging support for both browsers.
I found after hours of testing, that Suns **Netbeans** is the best PHP and Python IDE for Windows and Linux. I was surprised that also Javascript support can hold the candle to Aptana. 
So Netbeans is my recommendation (not only for Javascript).

Give it a try, its free!

Answer (score 9):

I've found [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) to be good.

Comment: Does Aptana support in IDE debugging of Javascript?

Comment: what about auto complete?

Answer (score 6):

I tend to recommend more and more [Netbeans](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018231756/http://netbeans.org/features/javascript/index.html) <strike>that has not been proposed yet</strike> (I am blind sometimes). Netbeans is developed by Sun and support not only Java but also a few other languages (PHP,Ruby,Python, Javascript).

I use it for a while now and I am very satisfied. It is fast, provides code completion and integrates easily major JS libraries (Prototype, YUI). It has also a debugger that you can tied to FF or IE.

Try it you won't be disappointed!

Answer (score 5):

[Komodo IDE](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/) (or the [free Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) if you can live without an integrated debugger) are pretty nice.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good list of IDEs you can use for writing JavaScript:

http://www.programmerfish.com/top-8-ide-integrated-development-environment-for-java-script-html5-ajax/

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays I am using JetBrains' PHPStorm and I can easily say, this is the best editor I've ever tried. Comes with lots of features that I have not seen at other editors like,

- find a word in a directory (grep equivalent)
- extended and useful intellisense feature with multiple files and parent classes
- internal GIT support
- a tree view for application structure
- an awesome version history support that works with GIT and your local history. This is very useful when you want to take a look at a GIT untracked file, you can see all history details of the file for weeks.
- with a great addon named CSSXFire that works with Firebug and tracks the CSS changes and import them to editor and allows you easily reproduce the same changes that you've done in Firebug CSS Console. This is really awesome
- another useful feature is, when you want to delete or rename a file, editor searches the file has been used in this directory and notifies you. This is called `safe-refactor`
- intellisense for files, while you typing a css background-image, a src or an href attribute

Sometimes I deal with PHP so I prefer PHPStorm, so Front End Developers should prefer WebStrorm that is specialized for us.

I think, every FE Developer should try PHPStorm or WebStorm with Firefox and Firebug.

Comment: After many years of development in DW - PHPStorm was a big discovery. After a few weeks of work in PHPStorm I got back to DW and it seemed totally outdated. I could compare it to my experience when I got my hands once again on Win PC after buying my first Mac - it felt like it was totally wrong!) So PHPStorm is the best one, yeap!

Answer (score 3):

I tried few IDE last week and NetBeans is my winner. It got silent upload option for file upload in background. And very good code completion, folding, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my experience with the applications based on Extjs in UI with Java as server side language. I am a big supporter of open source technologies/products.

I so far I have used Eclipse, Netbeans, Webstorm and notepad++ with some added plugins.

And I feel Netbeans is best in terms of Syntax highlighting and formating. It recognizes missing commas, global variables, duplicate keys for object literals in a very impressive way.

Almost similar things can be achieved by adding some pligins like Spket in eclipse too, but it asks for licence when you go for advance level of settings.

If you are not so much concern about an integrated environment with web server then Web storm is best in all the aspects, but the biggest drawback of it is, "Its paid". ( Even if it asks for 1000 Rs ).

Answer (score 2):

Firebug and a good syntax highlighting text editor is about the best combo. It's not necessary to add in much else. With just this combo you get:

- Ability to set breakpoints
- Inspect objects
- Traverse the DOM
- Alter CSS rules on the fly
- See network traffic/responses
- Evaluate and substitute code on the fly in production

And there are tools which add on to Firebug:

- [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) - Determine "why" your page is slow
- [Fireunit](http://fireunit.org/) - Run unit tests

One of the advantage of Javascript development is that it's flexible and you can get instantaneous feedback while developing. I see no reason to get in the way of that by adding an IDE which includes a "deployment" step.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ comes with built-in javascript syntax highlighting and [JSlint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/) plugin is very handy. IMHO for debugging there is nothing better than Chrome developer tools or Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

This page reviews the most advanced Javascript IDEs (in terms of refactoring and intellisense anyway) :

http://blue-walrus.com/2013/08/review-javascript-ides/

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse and JSEclipse plugin and of course Firefox + Firebug the ultimate duo. You'll find this development setup satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana is a great IDE as it will provide intelli-sense for CSS, javascript, html, java, etc.  The debugger gives you the choice to run in FF or IE and is a full featured debugger.  The community edition allows you to run a server side javascript as well.  A very solid and feature rich platform for free.