# The best javascript development environment?

Tags: javascript, ide

What is the best windows environment to use while developing web application with heavy javascript coding? Does any tools other than VS have some kind of intellisense for javascript?

Comment: There are a ton of questions that are almost the same as this, so here is the most recent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788978/ide-for-javascript-development I personally use Aptana w/Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [cloud9ide](http://cloud9ide.com/), [netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/), [vs2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us), [webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

I mean have your pick!

Cloud9IDE is a web based IDE thats run in a server. You just go to the website and develop, write and debug your code in the browser. Just login and write. But this is in closed beta and very young. It needs to mature

Netbeans is familiar for those who have used it for java. It's javascript support is good and compared to aptana, eclipse & vs2010 I prefer it.

WebStorm is a great IDE made for front-end developers. This like VS isn't free but it's significantly cheaper then VS. I would recommend WebStorm currently for having good features like intellisense, git integration and refactoring tools build in.

Of course you can always use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/download.php/), [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

'Best' is very much relative to the user. Personally, I've used Komodo Edit (if my memory serves me correctly has intellisense for JS), Eclipse (dunno about intellisense), Notepad++, Vi and finally Emacs.

Emacs is my editor of choice for everything. If you know your way around the commands, key binds and system commands well enough (if you're on Windows, you should install Cygwin and learn it imho), it's without a doubt the most effective dev environment available.

(No need to spark a religious emacs vs. vi debate here - I do like Vi too, just not as much ;))

Comment: be aware that there are various tools in IDEs that you don't find in text editors like refactoring tools, intellisense and svn/cvs integration

Comment: Sure.. However, you could very easily integrate anything that you want into emacs (there are TONS of packages out there). It all boils down to personal taste really - I like things as lightweight as possible, adding where I see fit. Was just my 2c :) (pretty sure emacs comes with vc-git out of the box now)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans works as good as anything for me - but it's really down to personal taste! There's loads out there, give them a go and see what works best for **you**.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate. Lightweight, performs very well, extremely configurable, lots and lots of nice built-in bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I know you say 'other than VS,' but Visual Studio 2010 has really great javascript support.  Have a look at these posts by Scott Gutherie on the subject:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/08/javascript-intellisense-improvements-with-vs-2010.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

The second post applies to improvements introduced in Visual Studio 2008, but it certainly holds true for the 2010 edition.  If you are needing intellisence in your standalone script files I suggest you read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/11/06/jscript-intellisense-a-reference-for-the-reference-tag.aspx) on the subject.  Do you find something lacking in Visual Studio's javascript support that has you searching for another solution?

Comment: Visual Studio is so heavy and bulky for just javascript. He might want something lighter. Not to mention that VS licences are expensive.

Comment: @Raynos I agree with you, however since he mentioned VS I thought it was good just to discuss the features it offers for javascript editing in case he was not aware.  Without knowledge of the reference path feature, for example, one might not think they could only get intellisence for external files with document inline javascript, and the IDE would appear far less attractive to them.