# C3js load csv, JSON data fail

Tags: javascript, csv, c3.js

I've tried everything I can think of but can not find the answer to my seemingly simple problem.

I need to load data to C3.js with from a csv file.

I have set everything up as the [documentation suggests](http://c3js.org/samples/data_url.html)

Here is my code -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="../css/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../js/c3.js"></script>
    <script>

      var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
          url: '../data/c3_test.csv'
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know the .js and two .css files are in the right place, because every other template works. The csv is in the right place (I believe) but nothing happens.

I have tried loading .json, which is in the same folder, but nothing.

This must be something simple but I am losing my mind.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The Network tab in Google Chrome lists every other doc, like .css and .js docs, but not my .csv file. How can this be?

**EDIT**

Answer from Github says the file:// handler blocks XMLHttpRequests. I'm running these files from my desktop.

I will install a server and get back about it.

Comment: have you added your c3.js properly.

Comment: How do you mean added? I placed the c3.js file in the /js folder, just copied all files from the source on Github. Is there something more to it?

Comment: on it is fine see in console if you are getting any error. if you want to verify directly use this in your src:https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/c3.js and check for surety.

Comment: Says there was a bunch of errors. One was 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load'. Cross Origin request. Then this line in c3.js (line1856) failed: 'd = $$.convertCsvToData(data.response); 
This all makes zero sense to me.

Comment: are you running chrome??????????????/

Comment: Yes, also tried in Mozilla FF. Gave me different errors. In Mozilla I get NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied on line 1 of d3.min

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was to download [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505389/recommend-a-development-environment-for-html5-javascript) on dev environments said that program was good for learners.

The moral to the story is the file:// handler can not always manage xmlhttprequests, like loading from a .csv or .json file.

Alternatively, Safari will handle these requests.

Comment: You might be running into the [following issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787) with Chrome. TL;DR you have to start Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`. Should be a different issue on Mozilla.

Comment: Yes it was a different error in Mozilla. thanks for link