# what is your suggestion for a simple javascript editor with code completion?

Tags: javascript, windows, ide, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

could you please let me know about good IDEs available for javascript programming?

I am looking for a no-frills, simple editor focussing primarily on the below functionalities -
a) syntax highlighting
b) auto-suggest for code completion

Note - I use windows 7, and have tried Aptana Studio. I do not want editors as powerful as aptana..something like simple looking notepad++, with a feature rich code-completion algorithm would do.

If this question is off topic, I apologize.

Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer at another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788978/ide-for-javascript-development/5567931#5567931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess after a lot of googling, I've found the best solution to my own question :)

Here's what I think is the best Javascript IDE: CODELOBSTER IDE
http://www.codelobster.com/js_editing.html

Why? 
1. Code-autocomplete
2. Syntax Highlighting
3. Not just JS, the above two features are functional for PHP, xHTML, CSS..!!
4. Did I mention its FREEEEEEEEEEEEE....?

Guys, let me know how you find this software.

Answer (score 2):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is definitely the way to go.

I've used Notepad++ in the past since I didn't want to use a full fledged IDE, but was never really happy with it. I've since switched to Sublime Text, and never looked back.

Comment: may i know whether sublime text offers code-completion, like how you see in netbeans/ aptana? sublime text looks good enough, if it offers this feature too..

Answer (score 1):

How about eclipse and a full blown javascript, jsp environment eclipse.org.... Granted the learning curve can be huge, its powerful!

Comment: -1 as this is the exact opposite as was asked for

Answer (score 0):

[PsPad](http://www.pspad.com) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) are simple but powerfull editors for many languages.
You also have the big [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliossr1).

Other JavaScript only editor :

[FreeJavaScript editor](http://download.cnet.com/Free-JavaScript-Editor/3000-10248_4-10907077.html)