# how to manage javascript or front project

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

In our project, we want to add a new javascript project include javascript and css, it is an front size project, and there are many module js which will be merged into main js, at the same time, the main js will be compressed into a *-min.js just like jquery. but now all the process is manually and easy to get mistake. may I know is there a tool or eclipse plugin to handle js project like this? or is there any better manner to process? thanks.

Comment: Why the Java tag? What does your question have to do with Java programming?

Comment: sorry, my fault, I amended it

Comment: You can use http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/ for the `*-min.js` part.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. I still don't see in your latest question where Java is involved. JavaScript, yes, but again, how is Java part of this problem? You do know that they are completely different languages, right?

Comment: have you, i dunno, googled it? http://bit.ly/1fTLVez

Comment: I deleted the eclipse tag~~, amended again.

Comment: thank you Elliott, really help me partly

Answer (score 1):

If you were asking for javascript ide, try http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: I will try it first, may I know is there IDE with free license? thank you very much

Comment: yw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788978/ide-for-javascript-development could help you find one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/, which also has a [downloadable jar](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) and [REST api](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api?csw=1)